# QListWidget doesn't allow icon size greater than 200

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

`QListWidget::setIconSize` with size > 200x200 doesn't seem to have any effect. Is it intended, or am I doing something wrong? There's no mention of such cap in the doc. Could there be another property that's limiting icon size?

I'm using Qt 5.

Comment: Are your images used in your icons of that size? I just searched in the Qt source code, there is no mention of `200` in the source code related to a maximum icon size. Did you guess this size or are you sure it is *exactly* 200 pixels?

Comment: No I tested with 600x600 and it works

Comment: @leemes: Thanks a lot! The icons are indeed of that size. I've resized them to lower memory consumption and completely forgot about it. Please post an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your source images seem to have that size you are experiencing as the icon size limit. The `QListWidget` won't draw the icon larger than the source image.

You should use a larger source image.